# Sibling element inheriting opacity

Tags: jquery, html, css, opacity

I have the following problem - anytime I click on photo I want it to become .3 opac and the `.remove-icon` element to be visible. And it works as intended, however, the icon is somehow inheriting the image opacity. How to prevent that? My code below

HTML

```
<div id="photos-wrapper">
  <div>
    <div class='remove-icon'> <i class="fas fa-times"></i> </div>
    <img src='http://dev.app.ucado.co.uk/${pamiec.photos[e]}' width='200px' height='150px'>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class='remove-icon'> <i class="fas fa-times"></i> </div>
    <img src='http://dev.app.ucado.co.uk/${pamiec.photos[e]}' width='200px' height='150px'>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class='remove-icon'> <i class="fas fa-times"></i> </div>
    <img src='http://dev.app.ucado.co.uk/${pamiec.photos[e]}' width='200px' height='150px'>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#photos-wrapper .remove-icon {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #ff0000;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(photosContainer).on('click', 'div', function(e) {
 $(this).find('img').animate({opacity: '.3'}, 300);
 $(this).find('.remove-icon').css('opacity', '1');
})
```

Comment: maybe an optical illusion ?

Comment: no it's not. When I apply opacity: 1 in css it's fully visible

Comment: can you create a full snippet ... i suspect some wrong CSS .. you also apply your logic to any div on click

Comment: there is nothing more in css. the only thing I did not include here is that photos are generated with javascript, nothing else

Comment: so all your icons are absolute position ? in this case all of them should overlap if it's all the CSS you have

Comment: no, photos have default position, presumably block

Comment: i meant the icons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you viewing your `opacity: 1` icon through your transparent image. You want the icon to appear overtop. You could do this by adding a z-index to the icon, but I'd rather reorder the html so the icons are added after:

```
<div id="photos-wrapper">
  <div>
    <img src='http://dev.app.ucado.co.uk/${pamiec.photos[e]}' width='200px' height='150px'>
    <div class='remove-icon'> <i class="fas fa-times"></i> </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src='http://dev.app.ucado.co.uk/${pamiec.photos[e]}' width='200px' height='150px'>
    <div class='remove-icon'> <i class="fas fa-times"></i> </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src='http://dev.app.ucado.co.uk/${pamiec.photos[e]}' width='200px' height='150px'>
    <div class='remove-icon'> <i class="fas fa-times"></i> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's right... it works now. But it's really doggy whatsoever, these are siblings elements, they shouldn't have any affect on each other

Comment: @DavidC. there should be more CSS for the other element :) it's impossible to have this behavior with only this CSS ... the icon is place on the top/right and the image is 200px wide so for normal screen there is no way to the icon to overlap the image with ONLY the CSS you show ... so don't tell me that on your page you have only this CSS, i won't trust you ;)